# How to use gtalk with 2-step verification login

Tags: login, google-talk

I have turn on 2-step verification for my Google account and I cannot login [Gtalk](http://www.google.com/talk/intl/en-GB/index.html) desktop application.

I did try to use application specific passcode as recommended [here](http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/chat/avzdT2cWN68/DMiMvq5m04EJ) but I still getting the error `Internal server error` as the snapshot below.

Any workaround for me?

[image]

Answer (score 9):

The answers here appear to be out of date. So here are the new instructions:

1. Go to your Google Security Settings (https://www.google.com/settings/security)
2. Find "App Passwords", and choose "Settings" ([direct link](https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords)).
   [image: The settings button]
3. Click on "Select App"

[image: The Select App box]

4. choose "Other *(customized name)*"

[image: Select app menu options]

5. Enter a name that identifies which app will be using your GTalk account (e.g. "Pidgin Instant Messenger").
6. Click the "Generate" button just after the name you entered.
7. In the box that appears, select and copy the password inside the yellow box.

[image: Password box example]

Paste that password as your password into your app.

Comment: This also works for Trillian

Answer (score 3):

If you have enabled 2-step authentication, then you need to create a separate password for each app where you use the Google credentials.

Log into your google account, then go to Account --> Security
Click view all in Account Permissions box OR go to             https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions

Then click on Manage application-specific passwords link (log into the account if prompted)
Then type GoogleTalk in the box, click Generate password.
The generated password is the one you need to use in your google talk.

Answer (score 0):

Google talk was discontinued on February 23rd 2015. It is recommended giving Hangouts a try so you can chat with all your Google contacts. Hangouts supports people’s favorite features from Google Talk, including text chat, presence, contact lists and status messages. In addition, Hangouts lets you have group video chats, make phone calls, express yourself with emojis and keep your conversations going across Android, iOS, and your computer.

If messaging right from your desktop is important to you, try the Hangouts Chrome app or Hangouts in Gmail. If you’re not ready to make the switch to Hangouts quite yet, you can continue using Google Talk on Windows with a range of compatible third-party chat apps. (Please keep in mind these aren’t Google products, so exercise caution when signing in with your Google account.)